# L'adjectif « subjacent » ?

Tags: adjectifs, origine-ou-raison, latin, préfixes, santé-et-médecine

> ...des gens avaient une maladie [**subjacente**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/subjacent) qui...

Je pense que c'est la première fois que je rencontre l'adjectif avec le préfixe latin et évidemment que ça signifie *sous-jacent*.

En cooccurrence avec *maladie/pathologie*, lequel est le plus usuel, y a-t-il une différence et peut-on qualifier la nature de la concurrence ou de la complémentarité des deux (graphies d') adjectifs dans ce genre de contexte ?

Comment: @Lambie Cette référence concerne le *subjacent* occitan, pas son voisin septentrional.

Comment: @Lambie Non, *littéraire* et *sens figuré*. Ne mélange pas catégorie et définition. Personne ici ne doute du sens de subjacent.

Comment: Le mot subjacent et sous-jacent sont synonymes selong le TFLi: Littér. Qui se trouve en dessous. **Synon. sous-jacent**. L'écorce du globe et les couches subjacentes. Au fig. Caché.// Par contre, en médicine et finance, p. ex. sous-jacent est underlying en anglais. Une pathologie sous-jacente, an underlying medical condition. anglais subjacent is not used for an underlying medical condition or underlying asset (futures trading). actifs sous-jacents.

Comment: _Human genetics has shown to be broadly effective when evaluating subjacent genetic defects such as orphan genetic diseases, but on the other hand, a modest progress has been achieved toward comprehending the molecular pathologies and designing new therapies. Chemical genetics, placed at the interface of chemistry and genetics, could be employed to understand the molecular mechanisms of subjacent illnesses and for the discovery of new remediation processes._  (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29981392/). It may not be commonly used in the field but you still find some, maybe non native speakers

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille Probably bad translation: Look at all the Spanish or Portuguese names: Teodorico C Ramalho 1, Alexandre A de Castro 2, Tássia S Tavares 2, Maria C Silva 2, Daniela R Silva 2, Pedro H Cesar 2, Lucas A Santos 2, Elaine F F da Cunha 2, Eugenie Nepovimova 3, Kamil Kuca 4 In Spanish: underlying genetic defects are: defectos geneticos subyacentes

Comment: About 322 results (0.31 seconds) = subjacent genetic defects, most from the same people. About 130,000 results (0.41 seconds) = underlying genetic defects. Actually, they are from Brazil, so the word would be subjacente. Brazilians are notorious for producing writing like that in English.

Comment: Oui @Lambie, c'est très minoritaire. Maintenant qu'on sait ça on peut revenir à la question, puisque de savoir si subjacent est beaucoup utilisé en anglais ne relève ni de la question ni même du site. C'ést une simple possibilité qui pourrait expliquer pourquoi on l'emploierait en français, et oui les gens de l'étude sont des locuteurs d'Amérique du sud mais rien ne dit qu'ils sont responsables de la traduction. Par ailleurs dans l'[exemple](https://www.lapresse.ca/covid-19/2022-01-26/maman-je-pense-que-je-vais-mourir.php) qui avait éveillé ma curiosité, il s'agit assurément d'un anglophone...

Comment: ...qui s'exprimait en français. Mais peu importe, ça ne nous rapproche pas d'une réponse à la question « En cooccurrence avec maladie/pathologie, lequel est le plus usuel, y a-t-il une différence et peut-on qualifier la nature de la concurrence ou de la complémentarité des deux (graphies d') adjectifs dans ce genre de contexte ? » en français. Une réponse illustre qu'il s'agirait essentiellement d'une curiosité que cet emploi peu fréquent, ce qui répond pas mal à la question.

Comment: En français, pour une pathologie médicale on dirait sous-jacente. Mais je sais que vous (ici) ne vont pas me croire. Alors, je laisse tomber. On peut ne pas être francophone, ce qui est mon cas, mais être quand même très experimentée dans certains domaines à cause d'une profession.

Comment: Oui mais j'ai rencontré « Des études pancanadiennes montrent que la moitié des enfants hospitalisés pour une infection COVID-19 avaient une maladie subjacente qui les mettait à risque » et donc j'ai posé la question, qui n'a rien à voir avec ton affirmation. Je sais bien que sous-jacent est plus usuel comme j'ai affirmé n'avoir jamais rencontré subjacent avant. @Lambie Te croire à quel sujet ?? Dans le citation que je viens de produire _sous-jacent_ est plus usuel pour moi. C'est le point de départ de la question ! Tu peux être très expérimentée mais quel est le _bottom line_ de ton propos ?

Comment: Moi, au fil des années, j'ai constaté que surtout dans les domaine techniques, lorsqu'il y a deux mots synonymes, parfois les français et les Québecois utilisent l'un ou l'autre, et souvent pas le même. Une simple constation. Pour l'instant, je suis incapable de donner une autre exemple.

Comment: @Lambie Donc ce pourrait être un emploi régional de subjacent, parfois ça arrive ces choix différents au lexique selon les régions, comme avec _courriel_. Mais sur le site de lapresse, _subjacent(es)_ ne sort qu'une seule fois, dans l'exemple dont j'ai parlé, alors que sous-jacent sort 2000+ fois. Et l'article sur subjacent ds. le Wiktionnaire n'est pas marqué régional/Qc. Je pense que c'est plus une curiosité qu'un régionalisme, même si le phénomène dont tu parles existe dans certains cas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'adjectif du moyen-français *subjacent* a été utilisé par des savants sûrement familiers avec le latin et pour qui le doublon *sous-jacent* ne devait pas sembler nécessaire. *Subjacent* est cependant très rare avant 1800, nombreux sont les faux positifs qui sont en fait des textes en latin. *Sous-jacent* décolle rapidement et supplante quasi-totalement *subjacent* dès la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> comme le montrent les Google NGrams suivants.

#### Subjacent/subjacente :

[image]

Le petit retour en grâce en forme de podium olympique autour des années 1990 est associé à la forme *plan subjacent*, probablement remise au goût du jour par une réédition d'un livre d'anatomie ou de géométrie.

#### Sous-jacent/sous-jacente :

[image]

La prépondérance de cooccurrences du domaine médical pour *subjacent* montre une spécialisation que n'a pas *sous-jacent*, plus générique.

Les associations modernes de *subjacent* avec *maladie* et *pathologie* sont excessivement rares, sous le radar de NGram. Google n'en trouve qu'une poignée. Ce sont les formes modernes *maladie sous-jacente* et *pathologie sous-jacente* que l'on trouve aujourd'hui.

[image]

Il est possible que les très rares *maladies/pathologies subjacentes* soient dues à une influence de l'anglais *subjacent* plutôt qu'à une résurgence savante de l'ancien mot français.

De manière analogue, c'est probablement aussi d'une influence de l'anglais que provient *subcontinent* qui concurrence *sous-continent* quand il s'agit de parler de l'Inde.

[image]

Comment: Merci, donc c'est essentiellement une curiosité, un petit phénomène de rien. L'exemple que j'ai rencontré provenait d'un locuteur anglophone qui s'exprimait en français donc la possibilité que tu évoques est pertinente. Je me dis que ça vient parfois de l'anglais et qu'on parle de ça uniquement en maths ou en médecine, mais le francophone voit le trait latin comme prestigieux et l'emploie par la suite à petite échelle ? Peut-être que c'est l'influence de l'anglais dans le domaine médical cette spécialisation ? _Subjacent_ est-il plus « figeant » à cause de sa morpho., _sous-conscient_ ?.

Comment: "Il est possible que les très rares maladies/pathologies subjacentes soient dues à une influence de l'anglais subjacent plutôt qu'à une résurgence savante de l'ancien mot français". The English for **sous-jacent** i= **underlying**. Une pathologie sous-jacent is an underlying illness or medical condition. Subjacent is a faux ami here.

Comment: Covid : "Il faut vacciner les enfants qui ont une **pathologie sous-jacente**" affirme Christophe Delacourt https://www.francebleu.fr/emissions/l-invite-du-matin/107-1/l-invite-de-france-bleu-paris-517  Translation: "Children with **an underlying medical condition** must be vaccinated", asserts Christophe Delacourt. underlying, sous-jacent is used in medicine and finance, to name just two.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, disons des semi-faux-amis puisque leur définition est la même. *Subjacent* n'est en effet quasiment pas employé en anglais pour *disease* et semble aussi assez passé de mode pour le reste. C'est quand même peut-être sous l'influence inconsciente d'un anglais imaginaire ou du globish que sont nés les rares cas trouvés en français. Google trouve quand même six fois plus de *subjacent disease* que de "maladie subjacente".

Comment: @Lambie Le fait que _underlying illness_ (voire _preexisting_) soit ce qui est le plus usuel ne change en rien l'existence du mot en anglais et donc sa connaissance par certains locuteurs anglophones.

Comment: @Ti-culTi-caille underlying is not pre-existing, exactly. There is no English interference here at all. This is entirely a French and French Canadian thing. That's the most likely reason you found: maladie subjacente et non pas à cause de l'anglais.

Comment: @Lambie Non ce n'est pas limité au Français. On trouve pas mal de *subjacent pathology* dans des documents rédigés par des chercheurs de langue espagnole, portugaise, italienne ou roumaine, c'est pour ça que j'ai parlé de globish. Disons que c'est un mot anglais que certains non-anglophones croient pouvoir utiliser en anglais dans un contexte où un anglophone natif utiliserait autre chose.